# Spark Scala Method Signature in DataFrame API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, syntax, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying to understand scala more and I think I am a little lost with this method signature.

```
explode[A <: Product](input: Column*)(f: (Row) ⇒ TraversableOnce[A])(implicit arg0: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.TypeTag[A]): DataFrame
```

First off, what is the "<:" supposed to mean in the square brakcets?  Are A and B supposed to be parameter types?  But Column is the argument type.

Secondly, it looks like it does a lambda function from (Row) to Traversable[A] but I haven't seen a lambda yet that doesn't have the left side argument on the right side argument at least once.

Also, I 'm not 100 percent usre why it has the implicit arg0: piece

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the "<:" supposed to mean in the square brackets?

`<:` means subtype in scala, so here it means the `A` is a subtype of `Product`. It acts like a kind of upper bound which limits the type that can be passed here to be subtype of `Product`

> Are A and B supposed to be parameter types? But Column is the argument
>   type

`A` is not the parameter type, it is a parameter by itself, which is called type parameter. It is a little bit confusing but basically it means you can pass any type that is a subtype of `product` to this position and use the type parameter inside the function. This makes the function more generic because it can handle different types at the same time and you don't have to write separate functions for different types;

> it looks like it does a lambda function from (Row) to Traversable[A]

`f: (row) => Traversable[A]` is another parameter which in this case is a function type which accepts `(row)` and return `Traversable[A]`. By this definition, `explode` can accept a function as a parameter, in which case is a lambda expression;

To illustrate the last case:

```
def sum(x: Int, y: Int)(f: Int => Int) = f(x) + f(y)
sum: (x: Int, y: Int)(f: Int => Int)Int

sum(2,3)(x => 2*x)
res2: Int = 10
```

In conclusion, the function explode accepts three parameters in total, the first one `A` is a type parameter. The second and the third are real arguments of the function, with `Input` being of type `Column` as you have noticed and `f` being of type `(row) => Traversable[A]` which is a function type.

Comment: Does f,  the function,  always need to be in a different set of parenthesis when you define parameters of "regular"  types and a parameter of a function type?  Would it ever look something like (a: Int,  b:Int,  f: (Int)  => Int)  or would it ever look like (a: Int,  b:Int,  (f:(Int)  => (Int))) ?  Thanks and sorry about the confusing "B"  haha

Comment: It doesn't have to be as you can test in a scala REPL. Both `(a: Int, b:Int, f: Int => Int)`  and `(a: Int, b:Int)(f: Int => Int)` work, but you have to call them in the same way you define them. The latter allows you to pass the parameters in two steps which sometimes gives you advantages.